# How to make the command Text a function

Tags: functions

I want to create a function  as follows:  g[x_]:=Graphics[Text["mean=" x, {a,b}]]. That is at some coordinate point (a,b) the text, mean = x is printed.  I get 3mean=   when I use this function, i.e. g[3]

Comment: Use `Row` or `StringTemplate`, now you are just multiplying.

Comment: Or [StringForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
g[x_] := Graphics[Text[Row[{Style["mean=", 16], Style[x, 16]}], {0, 0}]]
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
g[x_]:=Graphics[Text["mean="<>ToString[x], {a,b}]]
```

Comment: `g[1/2]` is not going to do what you want because of the default behavior of `ToString`.

Comment: @BrettChampion Ok, it doesn't look nice for $x=1/2$, but it works for $x=0.5$.