# Parentheses in axis labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

For my masters thesis I need plots of squared Bessel Processes, but I can't get the axis lables right. I want the y-axis to be labeled
$$\left(R_s^{(n)}\right)^2$$
but I have not been able to get the big parentheses in the right position. The best I have accomplished is this:

```
ListLinePlot[{matris1, matris2, matris3}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, 
   SuperscriptBox["(" Subscript[R, t]^"(n)" ")", 2] // DisplayForm}]
```

which gives this plot
[image]

As you can see the parentheses are in the wrong place. Any ideas on how to get it right?

Comment: [123146](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123146/5478), [145059](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145059/5478)

Comment: Perhaps related: [(21082)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21082/121)

Comment: @Kuba I see you were still adding links to the header.  *Now* I think the question "already has an answer" so I agree with the close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be close enough.   If you really need to dial it in consider [LaTeX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/736/121).

```
RowBox[{"(", SubsuperscriptBox["R", "s", "(n)"], ")"}]^2 // 
  DisplayForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer using [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes) instead of [`DisplayForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayForm), but of course that requires that you use valid boxes, which I think is a good thing.

Comment: @CarlWoll Good tip.  I know about `RawBoxes` but I have a hard time breaking old habits, including `DisplayForm`.  `DisplayForm` does work with mixed forms however which I had seen as a convenience.  Do I infer correctly that you recommend avoiding e.g. `RowBox[{"(", Subsuperscript["R", "s", "(n)"], ")"}]^2 // DisplayForm` (with `Subsuperscript` rather than `SubsuperscriptBox`)?

Comment: Yes, I don't like mixing expressions and boxes. Many times I have to fix bugs where somebody uses a mixture of expressions and boxes that don't work. One example: what should DisplayForm["a"]//TraditionalForm look like? Should it be italicized or not?